# Solving an ASP.Net Web Service, Maximum Array Error on an auto-generated Web Service class

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, wcf, web-services

I have a WinForms project that consumes a couple ASP.Net web services.  I'm trying to call one of my web service methods which returns a lot of data.  When I call the method, the application crashes and I'm getting the following error:

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter MyWebService:MyMethod. 
The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object 
of type MyNamespace.MyNameGivenToAutoGeneratedWSClass.MY_MethodResponseBody. 
The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML 
data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property 
on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. 
Line 1, position 28309.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

This problem has been addressed numerous times on StackOverflow but I can't find a solution that is specific to my case which makes use of an auto-generated Web Service classes within a Visual Studio project, that I also initialize within my code with manually defined binding and end-point objects.

How can I increase the maximum size for the returned XML? I've tried to increase the value of `MaxReceivedMessageSize`, `MaxBufferPoolSize` and `MaxBufferSize` on my `BasicHttpBinding` object that I pass into my Web Service constructor, but that didn't help.

What am I do wrong?

FYI, below is the code that initializes one of my web service classes for my application.

```
private void InitWebService()
        {
            if (Authorizer.UseWAN)
            {
                BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding();

                //10MB is more than enough for any of my result sets.
                //I'm not sure that this is the correct approach to
                //solving this problem.
                b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
                b.MaxBufferPoolSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
                b.MaxBufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
                EndpointAddress e = new EndpointAddress("This is an internal, company WAN address which uses HTTP");
                _appSyncClient = new ApplicationSyncSoapClient(b, e);

            }
            else
            {
                BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
                b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
                b.MaxBufferPoolSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
                b.MaxBufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
                EndpointAddress e = new EndpointAddress("This is an external connection point, using HTTPS.");
                _appSyncClient = new ApplicationSyncSoapClient(b, e);
            }
        }
```

Should I be handling this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found my own answer, after snooping around in Intellisense.  I'm posting an answer, just in case anyone else has the same problem in the future.

The `BasicHttpBinding` class has an object on it called `ReaderQuotas`, which is an instance of `XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas`.  This class also has a few maximum size limitation properties.

I amended my above initialization method to the following code.  This has solved my problem.

```
private void InitWebService()
    {
        if (Authorizer.UseWAN)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding();

            //10MB is more than enough for any of my result sets.
            //I'm not sure that this is the correct approach to
            //solving this problem.
            b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
            b.MaxBufferPoolSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
            b.MaxBufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
            b.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
            b.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
            b.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

            EndpointAddress e = new EndpointAddress("This is an internal, company WAN address which uses HTTP");
            _appSyncClient = new ApplicationSyncSoapClient(b, e);

        }
        else
        {
            BasicHttpBinding b = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
            b.MaxBufferPoolSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
            b.MaxBufferSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
            b.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
            b.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
            b.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

            EndpointAddress e = new EndpointAddress("This is an external connection point, using HTTPS.");
            _appSyncClient = new ApplicationSyncSoapClient(b, e);
        }
    }
```